# Regex, match all char between all square brackets matches only the last occurence

Tags: regex

I think its really stupid question but I don't find where is my mistake...

I have this sample string :

```
...

foo

[test1]
test2
test3
[test4]

faa

[test5]
test6
test7
[test8]
[test9]
test10    

fii

...
```

I want get all string between brackets between 'foo' and 'faa' strings, so the expected result must be 'test1' and 'test4'

I use this regex pattern `/foo.*\[(.*?)\].*faa/sm`, but I get only "test4" instead of 'test1' and 'test4'. I don't understand why :/

Here, the live example : https://regex101.com/r/KDPIEI/9

Thank you !

Comment: Are there any cases you don't want to match?

Comment: Please tell us which regex tool/language you are using, as this probably determines what answer you really need here.

Comment: I use the php language :)

Comment: You need `(?:\G(?!^)]\s*(?:\w+\R)*|foo)\s*\[\K[^][]+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/r0Z5fp/1)) or something like that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That pattern [isn't working in this demo](http://rextester.com/AAPUGC88744).  But, given that it's almost 2am here, I'm going to sleep now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As I say, "something like" that because the question is still sort of unclear. See [this demo](http://rextester.com/FFYVJ47138)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you :) but I really want match only strings between 'foo' AND 'faa" ;) I completed my initial post with a complete example

Comment: @user2137454 My feeling here is that you might get better mileage just using regex to isolate the text you really want to target.  Then, just do a blanket find all.

Comment: @user2137454 OK, [this is what you need](https://regex101.com/r/r0Z5fp/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach which first isolates the text you want between the `foo` and `faa` markers.  Then, it uses a simple pattern with `preg_match_all`:

```
$input = "[blah]\nfoo\n\n[test1]\ntest2\ntest3\n[test4]\n\nfaa\n[blah]";
if (preg_match("/(?<=\bfoo\b).*(?=\bfaa\b)/s", $input, $match)) {
    preg_match_all ("/\[(.*?)\]/", $match[0], $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
}

Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test4
)
```

### Demo